# Неправильный вывод программы в С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть функция, написанная на С++, которая должна раскладывать числа от 1 до N на простые составляющие - то есть, например, 2 - 2, 3 - 3, 4 - 2 и 2, и так далее. 
При вызове функции, в вывод попадает так же единица, но только когда число является двойкой в какой-либо степени. 
В чем моя проблема?

```
void simple_num (unsigned int N) {
unsigned int *simNums = new unsigned int; //Все простые найденные числа до N
simNums[1]=2; //Первое простое число
int n=2; 
for (int i=2; i<N+1; i++){ 
    int q=i;
    cout << i << ": " ;
    for (int j=1; j<n+1; n++){ //проверка делимости на известные простые числа
        if (q%simNums[j]==0){
            cout << simNums[j] << " ";
            q=q/simNums[j];
        } else { //найдено простое число? Ух ты...
            n++;
            simNums[n]=q;
            cout << q;
            break; 
        } 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
delete simNums;
}




Вывод:
2: 2 1
3: 3
4: 2 2 1
5: 5
6: 2 3
7: 7
8: 2 2 2 1
9: 9
10: 2 5
11: 11
12: 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дальше этого

```
unsigned int *simNums = new unsigned int; //Все простые найденные числа до N
simNums[1]=2; //Первое простое число
```

не стал и смотреть.

Вы выделяете память для **одного** числа, `simNums[0]`, и сразу пишете за пределы выделенной памяти - в `simNums[1]`. После этого говорить вообще не о чем...

Но вы поразили еще и этим:

```
for (int j=1; j<n+1; n++)
```

Итак, если `n` равно хотя бы 1, что будет? `j` равно 1.
Итерация 1. `1 < 2` - выполняем тело цикла...
Итерация 2. `1 < 3` - выполняем тело цикла...
Итерация 3. `1 < 4` - выполняем тело цикла...
... и так далее...  Может, все же `++j`? :)

И это еще не все, но начните хотя бы с простейшего. И еще - поищите, здесь на сайте тема факторизации рассматривалась много раз.

Comment: Насчет ++j вы правы, но вот первое - разве это не динамический массив, у которого нет выделенной памяти вообще? В книге по С++ была именно такая формулировка...
Плюс к тому, теперь оно не раскладывает 8 например на 2, 2 и 2, а на 2 и 4

Comment: Написанное вами - динамически выделенный массив из единственного элемента. Думаю, что вы спутали динамически растущий массив (для этого нужно писать немало кода, или использовать готовый класс `vector`) и динамически выделяемый массив. Неверное разложение - вы не пытаетесь проверять делимость *на то же самое* значение еще раз.

Comment: Понял. Насчет готового класса знаю, но я еще немного побаиваюсь стандартной библиотеки. Странно, что моя поделка вообще пыталась работать, и каким-то образом выводила нужные последовательности с собственно, единственной проблемой - лишняя единичка в конце
Может, еще подкинете чего по данному вопросу изучить - конкретно по этому алгоритму и по подобным? :)

Comment: Да не бойтесь, она не страшная :) Конечно, для понимания очень полезно понабивать шишек - как у вас сейчас, чтоб потом понимать, что там внутри, так что вы идете верным, хотя и тернистым путем :) Ну, а что читать - поищите тут на сайте вопросы с тегом "книги" - там есть список литературы и по С++, и по алгоритмам.

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня вдохновили ^^